# MongoDB copy subset of collection to new collection

Tags: mongodb

I have a collection of about 25m records. What is the most efficient way of creating a **new collection** that is a subset of the last 1m?

I had this;

```
db.metric.find({}).sort({'createdAt': -1}).limit(1000000).forEach(function(doc){
   db.metricSubset.insert(doc);
});
```

But the query took so long to run I think it timed out and only saved about 34k.

Can it be done faster?

I am using version 2.4.8 of Mongo

Comment: Any limitations in upgrading to the latest version as `$out` is only available in MongoDB 2.6 and newer?

Comment: Not sure how risky that is. I'd have to look in to it. Possibly fine to do

Comment: This should help https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/release-notes/3.2-upgrade/

Answer (score 3):

You could try out another way would be to use an aggregation pipeline with `$out` which should be faster -

```
db.metric.aggregate([
 {$sort: {createdAt: -1}},
 {$limit: 1000000},
 {$out: 'metricSubset'}
])
```

Comment: "exception: Unrecognized pipeline stage name: '$out'" - am I using an older version or something?

Comment: yea it was added in 2.6 https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/operator/aggregation/out/

Answer (score 2):

you should try to upgarde to version 2.6 in order to use the aggregation framework and $out operator like this :

```
db.metric.aggregate([ {$sort: {'createdAt': -1}}, {$limit: 1000000}, { $out: "metricSubset" }]);
```

Comment: "exception: Unrecognized pipeline stage name: '$out'" - am I using an older version or something?

Comment: what version of mongodb are you using ? (type mongo --version in your terminal to know)

Comment: version 2.4.8 (i've updated my post with that info as well)